# Is there any possibility to use two or more versions of different Linux distributions working with the same TMP, SWAP or another partitions?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, swap

I usually have two different Linux distributions on my PC together,
as I want to be prepared for the crash of the one or the second system.

My computer is quite old and it has got just one 80 GB harddisk.
By now I have, as I think, 6 different partitions: Linux Mint, Lubuntu,
SWAP, TEMP, BOOT and my personal DATA. I´m not sure about the filesystem types,
but most of them are some Linux filesystems Ext4, Ext3 and even Ext2, that´s all,
only the BOOT partition has got some special filesystem (Linux too, possibly).

Because of the lack of space on my only harddisk I would like to know,
if it is possible to use the TEMP & SWAP partitions from both systems
without any problem.

Thank You for Your answers!

Comment: /tmp is deleted at every boot on all Linux systems, so you can re-use it. /swap can also be re-used, but that means you cannot use Hibernate anymore.

Comment: Have never needed or had a TMP partition, only use root and maybe home(data).  Newer versions of Ubuntu uses a swap file instead of partition.  Is this a 32 bit system, and have you thought of getting a bigger drive?  Usually quite easy to replace.

Comment: You acknowledge that 80GB is not much storage.  This is reason enough to aim for as few partitions as possible.  Ubuntu does not need separate partitions for any of these things; what do you expect to gain from having them all separate?

Comment: I would recommend to buy 2.5" SSD with 256-512Gb space. They are now cheap, IDE<->mSATA converters also exist if you have this problem.